# DNS Zone config with Centos Web Panel doesnt work

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, nameserver

I have been trying for hours now to setup my domain with the CentOS Web Panel and own nameservers.

I did change the nameserver at the domain registrar and entered the IP values for these nameservers, so:

```
ns1.domain.com resolves to IP1
ns2.domain.com resolves to IP2
```

**That works**, I did check that with ping `ns1.domain.com`

But if I try to **ping `domain.com`, it doesn't work.**

My `domain.com.db` zone file:
(I replace the IPs with ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4)

```
; Generated by CWP
; Zone file for domain.com
$TTL 14400
domain.com.      86400        IN      SOA     ns1.domain. info.domain.com. (
                2019052314      ; serial, todays date+todays
                86400           ; refresh, seconds
                7200            ; retry, seconds
                3600000         ; expire, seconds
                86400 )         ; minimum, seconds


ns1.domain.com. 14400 IN A IP1
ns2.domain.com. 14400 IN A IP2
domain.com. 86400 IN NS ns1.salarom.com.
domain.com. 86400 IN NS ns2.salarom.com.


domain.com. IN A IP1


localhost.domain.com. IN A 127.0.0.1


domain.com. IN MX 15 domain.com.


mail IN CNAME domain.com.
www IN CNAME domain.com.
ftp IN CNAME domain.com.
; Add additional settings below this line
_dmarc 14400 IN TXT "v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mailto:info@domain.com"
domain.com. 14400 IN TXT "v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:IP1 ip4:IP2 ip4:IP3 ip4:IP4 ~all"
mta2 14400 IN A IP2
mta3 14400 IN A IP3
mta4 14400 IN A IP4
@ 14400 IN NS ns1.domain.com.
@ 14400 IN NS ns2.domain.com.
mail.domain.com 14400 IN A IP1
```

Hope you can help me!

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Solved!
Oh my god after like 6 hours of google & try and error i got it.
The zone (why ever) wasnt added to the named.conf by cwp ...
can be closed!